# My python app's email code will not update its template to a new version

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I'm running a python 2.7 app in google app engine. I have a very basic function that sends a post to the taskqueue, which then posts to a function that constructs and sends an email based on a few variables parsed into a mail template.

I'm not sure if the taskqueue is stuck on an old version of my app or what the problem is, but when I update the code in the file that sends the email, and upload the changes, those changes are not causing any the email text the app sends. It's like it's using a wrong older version of the file.

What could be the cause of this issue?

*edit*

Just of note, this is what I've tried so far.

- I tried updating the app to a new version, but there was no change
- I tried editing other files in the project, and they all seem to update correctly
- I am using the oauth method for uploading with a .bat file to run the command, and there's no refreshing needed there because updating the app version didn't help
- I tried moving the email code that I want to use out of its old class, into a new class, changed the main.py url to point to the new class, and it still uses the old email text
- I tried *removing the old url for triggering the email* and using an entirely new url, and it *still* uses the old email text
- I tried testing the app using the version-number.project-id.appspot.com format, and it *still* uses the old email text, which doesn't exist anywhere in that version

So to reiterate, I'm trying to send an email with my app, and even with the old message being totally removed, the email code being moved to a new file, and a new app version, somehow I'm still sending out the old email text.

*edit 2*

This is the relevant code for queuing the task:

```
taskqueue.add(url="/emailnotify", countdown = 1, 
                  params = {"email":tPaypalEmail, "gold":tGoldAmount, 
                            "name":tCustomerName, 'key':tOrderKey} )
```

This is the relevant code in the class that's supposed to send the email:

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
import webapp2

from models.order import Order
from google.appengine.api import mail
from google.appengine.ext import db, webapp

from _stringmethods import StringMethods
from _numbertogp import NumberToGp

class EmailNotify(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):

        tPaypalEmail = self.request.get('email')
        tCustomerName = self.request.get('name')
        tGoldAmount = self.request.get('gold')
        tOrderKey = self.request.get('key')

        tOrder = Order()
        tOrder = Order.get(tOrderKey)

        tVerificationCode = tOrder.orderVerificationCode

        tGoldInt = int(tGoldAmount)        
        tGoldAmount = NumberToGp.ConvertIntToBet(tGoldInt)

        tVerificationFile = cStringIO.StringIO()
        tVerificationFile.write(str(tVerificationCode))        

        #new message which does not appear in the app emails
        tMessage = """Long string formatted message""" % (str(tCustomerName), str(tGoldAmount), str(tVerificationCode)) 

        logging.debug(str(tMessage)) #this does not appear in the logs

        message = mail.EmailMessage()
        message.sender = "Smokin Mils Goldshop <Smokin.Mils.Goldshop@gmail.com>" #this email user is added as an app owner
        message.to     = tPaypalEmail
        message.subject = "SmokinShop Order Details"
        message.body   = tMessage
        message.attachments = [('verification-code.txt', tVerificationFile.getvalue())]

        message.send()
```

*edit 3*

In response to [the reddit question](http://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/1dcqln/my_python_apps_email_code_will_not_update_its/) where I posted this problem, here is the queue.yaml

```
queue:
- name: default
  rate: 60/s
  bucket_size: 50
  retry_parameters:
    min_backoff_seconds: 2
    max_backoff_seconds: 200
    task_retry_limit: 10
```

Comment: When you changed to a new version, did you select that version as the newfault (using the admin console)?

Comment: Yes. Like I said, I can modify other files, but it seems it is just this one file that won't change.

Comment: When you're enqueing a task, are you specifying an app version?

Comment: Negative. All I specify is the url, a countdown, and a few post parameters. I updated the OP with a few other things I tried.

Comment: Try this on a non-default version. Rename the file to something else, so that an error will be raised when your app tries to import it, upload the app and make sure the error is there (I think app engine deletes old files when a new version of your app doesn't include them, but I'm not sure). Once you see the error now rename your file back and upload your app again. I've seen app engine skip modified files esp if the modification was minor.

Comment: I found the problem. I was testing the app using an order generator that replicates paypal ipn POSTs, and I was posting to a hardcoded version url for a prior version that was still present, though not default, which caused it to run the old code. I discovered the bug by examining the headers for the requests in the task queue, and noticing they were POSTing to the prior version's url.

Comment: It's "off topic" because the problem was a versioning issue and not related to my code at all. I just had to change a config in the google app engine web admin console and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue when deploying several lines of an email servlet (on GAE/J) from Eclipse.  Finally fixed it after trying in vain the versioning, overwriting older versions, deleting version, playing around with tread-safe, changing the class name, changing the class signature (constructor) MemCache, etc. (none of this worked.)

**Bottom line**: delete 'deploy' and 'classes' folders in your WEB-INF directory.  Clean/build your project again.  Then upload to App Engine.

This 'deep clean / start over' approach seemed to do the trick.  What's annoying is that this never seemed necessary before.  It was only when I started playing with Email and PDF code using external libraries did this seem to cause issues.  I also upgraded to App Engine 1.8 recently.  Would love to know the root cause of this but I'm tired of doing Google's debugging for them at this point.  Just glad I seemed to find a solution.

Interesting background discussion: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7335

Comment: My mistake, I meant to close this question. I was referencing a hard coded url to an old version that I had added literally years ago and forgotten about, so the reason it wasn't updating is it was pointed it a different version than the one I was uploading. So the problem was entirely with me. =)